# Calculate median for an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects:

```
const bookDetails = [{"author":"john","readingTime":12123}, 
                     {"author":"romero","readingTime":908}, 
                     {"author":"romero","readingTime":1212}, 
                     {"author":"romero","readingTime":50}, 
                     {"author":"buck","readingTime":1902}, 
                     {"author":"buck","readingTime":12125}, 
                     {"author":"romero","readingTime":500},
                     {"author":"john","readingTime":10},
                     {"author":"romero","readingTime":230}, 
                     {"author":"romero","readingTime":189}, 
                     {"author":"legend","readingTime":12}
                     {"author":"john","readingTime":1890}]
```

I tried calculating the median for each author. Here is my function that calculates median for a given array:

```
//To calculate the median for a given array
function medianof2Arr(arr1) {
    var concat = arr1;
    concat = concat.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    var length = concat.length;

    if (length % 2 == 1) {
        // If length is odd
        return concat[(length / 2) - .5]
    } else {
        return (concat[length / 2] + concat[(length / 2) - 1]) / 2;
    }
}
```

But I want to calculate the median for *each* author separately. How can I do that?

#### Expected output

```json
{"john": 1890, "romero": 365, "buck": 7014, "legend": 12}
```

Comment: What is inside `arr1`?

Comment: Actually this was simply a function to calculate median of an array for if anyone needs on idea to calculate median, but I see that it will create confusion so, I removed it. I just want to calculate median for each author but unable to figure out how.

Comment: You need to group `readingTime` for each author and then call the median function on each array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first group your input by author, to get this data structure:

```json
{
    "john": [12123, 10, 1890],
    "romero": [908, 1212, 50, 500, 230, 189],
    "buck": [1902, 12125],
    "legend": [12]
}
```

And then you could call the median function on all those arrays and replace those arrays with the values you get back from the calls:

```js
function median(arr) {
    arr = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let mid = arr.length >> 1;
    return arr.length % 2 ? arr[mid] : (arr[mid-1] + arr[mid]) / 2;
}

const bookDetails = [{"author":"john","readingTime":12123}, {"author":"romero","readingTime":908}, {"author":"romero","readingTime":1212}, {"author":"romero","readingTime":50}, {"author":"buck","readingTime":1902}, {"author":"buck","readingTime":12125}, {"author":"romero","readingTime":500},{"author":"john","readingTime":10},{"author":"romero","readingTime":230}, {"author":"romero","readingTime":189}, {"author":"legend","readingTime":12},{"author":"john","readingTime":1890}];                         
                     
// Create a key for each author, and link them with an empty array
let result = Object.fromEntries(bookDetails.map(({author}) => [author, []]));
// Populate those arrays with the relevant reading times
for (let {author, readingTime} of bookDetails) result[author].push(readingTime);
// Replace those arrays with their medians:
for (let author in result) result[author] = median(result[author]);

console.log(result);
```

Note that the median for buck is not an integer 7014 as in your expected output, but 7013.5

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this

```
let bookDetails = [
    {"author":"john","readingTime":12123}, 
    {"author":"romero","readingTime":908}, 
    {"author":"romero","readingTime":1212}, 
    {"author":"romero","readingTime":50}, 
    {"author":"buck","readingTime":1902}, 
    {"author":"buck","readingTime":12125}, 
    {"author":"romero","readingTime":500},
    {"author":"john","readingTime":10},
    {"author":"romero","readingTime":230}, 
    {"author":"romero","readingTime":189}, 
    {"author":"legend","readingTime":12},
    {"author":"john","readingTime":1890}
];





const authorMap = bookDetails.reduce((acc, book) => {
    acc[book.author] ? acc[book.author].push(book.readingTime) : acc[book.author] = [book.readingTime]
    return acc;
}, {})

calculateMedian = (list) => {
    const sortedList = list.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    console.log(sortedList[Math.floor(sortedList.length / 2)]); // You might need to tweak this
}

for (let author in authorMap) {
    calculateMedian(authorMap[author])
}
```